# How to upgrade ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

I am facing issues in upgrading ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS.
I followed all online sources but could not pass through the initial stages

Got the following error when I tried from the terminal

```
$ /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version(‘Gtk’, ‘3.0’) before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

tried all possible help online

[Link1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323320&page=2)
[Link2](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391074)
[Link3](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/trouble-upgrading-from-16-04-to-18-04/16553)

It stops in the highlighted step, as shown in image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtACU.png)

Can any one help?

Closed: Reinstalled 16.04 and upgraded

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Upgrade the packages to the latest version for 16.04 decreases the chance of something going wrong during the upgrade to version 18.04. Run the command below

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Step 2:  Install the Ubuntu Update Manager.

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

Step 3: Upgrade Ubuntu

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After you enter the upgrade command, you will be asked to confirm that you want to update via SSH. Type `Y` to continue.

Step 4: After the upgrade is complete, a restart will be required.

Step 5:To check what version of Ubuntu is currently installed, use the command below.

```
lsb_release -a
```

---

Edit:

You will have to remove the PPA which were added to the system

Step 1: List the PPAs

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | \
    while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {print "sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5}' "$file"; done
```

Step 2: Now, remove them

```
find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | \
    while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {system("sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5)}' "$file"; done
```

Step 3: Install `bleachbit` and `gtkorphan`

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
sudo apt install gtkorphan
```

Step 4: Run `bleachbit` and `gtkorphan`as `root`

Step 5: Now, run the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

---

Edit

Step 1: Edit `apt` configuration

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to open `terminal`
Now, type

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Step 2: Change the config:

```
APT::Default-Release *;
```

**Note** If the `apt.conf` file does not exist, create your own user file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` so you can guarantee that it won't be overwritten by package updates. 
Use the command to create the file

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt.conf
```

Then to edit your file run

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/apt.conf
```

Add this line to thee file

```
 APT::Default-Release *;
```

Comment: I tried this earlier.. Step 3 gets Aborted

Comment: please share the error log

Comment: here is the [link](https://pastebin.com/6ca81Sxc)

Comment: no hope.. getting Aborted again

Comment: I dont see this file. I see apt.conf.d as directory. should I create one?

Comment: I did as you suggested and ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`. But the same result. Aborted

Comment: The first method working fine for me, I just tried upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 and it's work well.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking to do.

Either of these options should work.

```
apt full-upgrade
```

or

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope this helps!

Also I would hope it goes without saying but these need to be ran as the root user. If you aren't root just use

```
sudo su root
```

**------ UPDATE -------**

```
sudo su root

cd /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader
```

Look for a file with a name similar to

```
check-new-release-gtk:30:
```

Look for

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")

from gi.repository import Gtk
```

The version requirement may not be there. If it isn't we need to add it.

**------ UPDATE ------**

Try this ...

```
sudo do-release-upgrade

 sudo apt-get update --fix-missing; sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade;

sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After a bit of research I found this answer on an older post from last year. The wording was a bit different.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391552

Comment: I tried all these

Comment: Does it yield any error message?

Comment: Aside from the one above I mean.

Comment: Can you run "apt update" and post the results in an edit please. I believe we need to manually upgrade python and then upgrade the rest of the system.

Comment: <pre>Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB] 
Fetched 252 kB in 0s (280 kB/s)                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
<pre>

Comment: Thanks, give me just a few minutes I need to check some syntax and arguments. I may have a solution.

Comment: Okay, so here is what I found. It looks like they left out some coding or something was changed on the updater. The problem is that I don't have the same files there that you do. Good news is that I do have similar files so I have taken a look at them. My suggestion would be to open terminal and switch to root. (sudo su root) then "cd /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader"

Comment: Once there look for a file named something like this "check-new-release-gtk:30:" (as close as possible. Then open that file with your favorite text editor. (I like vi but most people use nano)

Comment: Inside that file there should be something along the lines of 
"import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk"

Comment: I just added it to the answer as an update.

Comment: I tried. Not working

Comment: Really? This is crazy because if you break down the error you posted it says that file that you edited is calling gtk but not specifying a version. Then it says that the version 3 is required and should be used in the import command. If follows by saying to re-run the import command with the version specified. The problem is we can't do that without editing the file and adding that in. (Which is what the last update was about.) I thought sure that was going to work. I have other ideas but they are a long shot. Try "apt show python" this will show what version of python you have.

Comment: My top problem is to upgrade and I am not bothered much about the warning. In one of the threads I saw that these errors can be ignored and not to worry too much on the warnings..

Comment: I just added a possible fix to the bottom of my answer. Please check.

Comment: I tried so many of these suggestions without any luck

Comment: This has to be very frustrating. Check out https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391552 (note that it fails at first but then works later on.)

Comment: tried this as well