# after updating to 18.04 from 16.04 there is no gui and can't upgrade

Tags: upgrade, gui

I coudln't install ubunut 18 so first I installed 16 and then I tried to upgrade.I downloaded 1 GB of upgrades but after reboot the login screen was still 16.04 version and after logging in there is just a backgroun and keyboard shortcuts don't work.I can open the terminal but I cant move the window!I tried every command I could find online:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgare
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
.
.
.
```

also when I run :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

it say that the following packages have unment dependencies...(un fortunatly I cant send the log since the gui is not working properly and I'm using another computer!)

please help me...I'm a newbie and don't know what to do

Comment: I have answered the question here https://askubuntu.com/a/1197202/890892

Comment: "*I coudln't install ubunut 18*" - exactly why not?

Comment: Don't focus on the upgrade -- looks like you upgraded. Focus on figuring out why you have unmet dependencies. You will need the log for that.